# Zybooks 5.12 counting negative temperatures

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that will take 6 integers and count how many are negative. It needs to be formatted like this:

```
Enter Celsius temperature:
30
Enter Celsius temperature:
20
Enter Celsius temperature:
-5
Enter Celsius temperature:
-18
Enter Celsius temperature:
-8
Enter Celsius temperature:
7
Number of below freezing temperatures: 3
```

Heres my code so far:

```
temp = int(input('Enter Celsius temperature:\n'))
temp_list = []
negtemp = 0

for i in range(6):
    while temp < 0:
        negtemp += 1
        temp_list.append(temp)
        
    
print('Number of below freezing temperatures: ', negtemp)
```

Comment: Think carefully about the logic of the program. How many times should `temp = int(input('Enter Celsius temperature:\n'))` happen - only once, or repeatedly for every temperature that will be checked? Therefore, should this code be inside of a loop, or outside? Is it?

Comment: BTW, this is the **same thing** that was wrong in the previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite your code like this,

```
negtemp = 0
for _ in range(6):
    temp = int(input('Enter Celsius temperature:\n'))
    if temp < 0:
        negtemp += 1
    
print('Number of below freezing temperatures: ', negtemp)
```

You aren tried to use `while` loop instead of `if` condition.